# How to use websocket on client side?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sockets, websocket

When **one user** adds an event using API, **other users** should get an alert about *new event*

Is it possible to:

**send message** from client-side when one user adds an event using `wss://echo.websocket.org`

```js
let socket = new WebSocket('wss://echo.websocket.org');
socket.onopen = () => socket.send('New event');
```

and **get this message** from other browser?

```js
let socket = new WebSocket('wss://echo.websocket.org');

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
  var message = event.data;
  alert(message)
};
```

server-side on **PHP**

Is there any source based on "How to realize WebSocket server ( PHP )"?

I don't want to send request to server every some **inetrval** for checking updates, is there any wat to **keep connection alive** and when got response show **alert** to the client?